# Method 'SetValueForUICulture' don't set other language value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, column, pnp-powershell

I have a problem with `SetValueForUICulture` method in my PowerShell script, I added field using method `Add-PnPField` and later according to what I found on the internet I tried use `SetValueForUICulture` method to change other language title (`TitleResource`).

Unfortunately after run script don't see changes, method `GetValueForUICulture('example')` return empty "Value". My attempts are as follows:

*Of course, when the fields already exist:

```
$myField = Get-PnPField -Identity "AssignedTo"
$myField.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture("pl-pl", "Example title")
$myField.Update() or $myField.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
```

later using

```
$myField.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture('pl-pl')
```

and return

[image]

please help, i searched all... :/

Comment: Obvious question, did you set pl-pl as an alternate language for the site?